# DBNull to type String is not valid ---Visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

Hello I have a problem  when I click into data grid I always get this problem I'm currently doing this for the update and i use the data grid view to make it easier I'll click in the data grid and the update button will be enabled and when I click the update button it will go to the form4 the maintenance module. But unfortunately the error "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid" get's always in my way so I can get to that part please help me thanks and again sorry for my bad english :))

```
Form4.txtEmpLastname.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("Lastname", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        Form4.txtEmpFirstname.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("Firstname", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        Form4.txtEmpMiddlename.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("Middlename", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        Form4.txtEmpAddress.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("CityAddress", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        Form4.txtEmpAge.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("Age", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        Form4.txtEmpBirthdate.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("Birthdate", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
        Form4.txtEmpBirthplace.Text = dgvEmployeeRecords.Item("Birthplace", dgvEmployeeRecords.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle these cases by passing your values into a method like below.

```
string HandleDBNull(object ObjectValue)
{
  if(ObjectValue is DBNull)
     return "";
  else
     return ObjectValue.ToString();
}
```

This is in C# and you'll need to translate it.  Then pass your objects into this method and assign the return value to your textbox text property.